# Regex Look Around Look Behind second , Look Ahead :

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Given this string:

U7PG2,f09fc22cdb13,v4.0.80.10875: hostapd: ath1: STA f2:9f:c2:2d:db:13 DRIVER: Sead AUTH addr=cc:44:63:0c:25:64 status_code=0

I am trying to match v4.0.80.10875

If I use this look around statement:
(?<=,)[^:]+(?=:) I match f09fc22cdb13,v4.0.80.10875

How can I tell it to look behind starting with the second "," in the string instead of the first?

Comment: Use a capturing group, `^(?:[^,]*,){2}([^:]+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGYrOD/1), just get Group 1 value.

Comment: That works, but with the Graylog software I am using it uses the Match as the result, not the capture group.  So in my case I need the match go be just v4.0.80.10875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always the v in the strings, you should be able to use:
`(?<=,)(v[^:]+)`

Comment: Bingo, it looks like there is indeed always a v.  Nice catch.